# Convert iPhone unique identifier to integer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uuid, uniqueidentifier

I have made a web service that gets an integer as a unique identifier for a Phone. Later, i realised that an iPhone UID is an NSstring in that format: 5DE31FA12-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXX. So i would like to convert this value to an integer.

Here is the way i get the UID in a NSString format.

```
CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
CFRelease(theUUID);
NSString *theUID = (NSString *)string;
```

How can i convert NSString *theUID into an integer value, so as to send it to the webservice?

***EDIT***: As CocoaFu correctly mentioned , it is impossible to fit that value in an int. Could I somehow convert it to an NSString with a format like "ddddddddddddddddddddddddddd" (where d = 0-9) so as to hash it and then send it? It is impossible to change the webservice now.

Comment: A uuid can not fit in a single integer!

Comment: either change your web service or make a new one

Comment: There are 36 ^ 26 = 3 x 10^40 possible UIDs. Even a long long integer only holds a value up to about 1 x 10^19.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The largest integer is 8 bytes or 64 bits.  The UUID you show has 26 hex characters which is 104 bits.  It just won't fit in an integer.  Use the string.

`CFUUIDCreate` returns a string with 32 hex characters, that is 128 bits or 16 bytes.  Ignore the '-' characters, they are just for human readability.  Here is an example from 
`CFUUIDCreate: BDFC3FE6-3A5E-48C0-B18D-E42B8E275428`

Answer (score 1):

UDID won't fit in an int. The format you have listed is what the simulator gives you. Device UDID is 40-characters long alpha-numeric.